# Allow calendar notifications in Do Not Disturb mode

Tags: macos, notifications, calendar, system-settings, do-not-disturb

Is there a way to configure Do Not Disturb on a per-app basis? Specifically, I would like to continue receiving calendar notifications even when Do Not Disturb is active. The options in system preferences are very limited.

[image: sys pref do not disturb]